# Fast implementation binary exponentiation implementation in OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, pow, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

I've been trying to design a fast binary exponentiation implementation in OpenCL. My current implementation is very similar to the one in [this book about pi](http://books.google.com/books/about/Pi_Unleashed.html?id=QwwcmweJCDQC).

```
// Returns 16^n mod ak
inline double expm (long n, double ak)
{
    double r = 16.0;
    long nt;

    if (ak == 1) return 0.;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n == 1) return fmod(16.0, ak);

    for (nt=1; nt <= n; nt <<=1);

    nt >>= 2;

    do
    {
        r = fmod(r*r, ak);
        if ((n & nt) != 0)
            r = fmod(16.0*r, ak);
        nt >>= 1;
    } while (nt != 0);
    return r;
}
```

Is there room for improvement? Right now my program is spending the vast majority of it's time in this function.

Comment: Any idea of what the general range of the input is?

Comment: n can range up to a million or so. So, a fairly large range of input.

Comment: Is `ak` actually double or an integer? What is it's range?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I'm back now. ak is (as far as I can tell) an integer. For some reason, this implementation treats it like a double (perhaps to avoid casting at some point?). I haven't actually tested the entire program with ak as an int instead of a double, so I don't know if making such a switch will reduce its accuracy or affect the performance in a later section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to vectorize it, for a potential speed up of ~1.6x. This uses 5 multiplies per loop compared to 2 multiplies in the original, but with approximately a quarter the number of loops for sufficiently large N. Converting all the `double`s to `long`s, and swapping out the `fmod`s for `%`s may provide some speed up depending on the exact GPU used and whatever.

```
inline double expm(long n, double ak) {

    double4 r = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    long4 ns = n & (0x1111111111111111, 0x2222222222222222, 0x4444444444444444,
            0x8888888888888888);
    long nt;

    if(ak == 1) return 0.;

    for(nt=15; nt<n; nt<<=4); //This can probably be vectorized somehow as well.

    do {
        double4 tmp = r*r;
        tmp = tmp*tmp;
        tmp = tmp*tmp;
        r = fmod(tmp*tmp, ak); //Raise it to the 16th power, 
                                       //same as multiplying the exponent 
                                       //(of the result) by 16, same as
                                       //bitshifting the exponent to the right 4 bits.

        r = select(fmod(r*(16.0,256.0,65536.0, 4294967296.0), ak), r, (ns & nt) - 1);
        nt >>= 4;
    } while(nt != 0); //Process n four bits at a time.

    return fmod(r.x*r.y*r.z*r.w, ak); //And then combine all of them.
}
```

Edit: I'm pretty sure it works now.

Comment: This looks awesome! Unfortunately, I don't have much time today to figure out exactly what your code is doing; I'll probably take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it working now. The gist of it is it uses vector types to process the input 4 bits at a time.

Comment: Hm... it doesn't seem to be working correctly. For example, in one of the first iterations on one of the first work items it has to calculate expm(6, 9) (in other words 16^6 % 9). expm() returns 9 when the answer is 1.

Comment: Looks like I had the select set up backwards and forgot an fmod on the return statement, although I don't see how both of those could cause that error. Any other broken cases to report?

Comment: Ah, spotted it. I had the wrong numbers in the select(..) part of the code, the wrong powers of 16.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45845/discussion-between-animatedjuzz-and-cactus1)

Answer (score 0):

- The loop to extract `nt = log2(n);` can be replaced by
   `if (n & 1) ...; n >>= 1;`
   in the do-while loop.
- Given that *initially* `r = 16;`, fmod(r*r, ak) vs fmod(16*r,ak) can be easily delayed to calculate the modulo only every Nth iteration or so -- Loop unrolling?
- Also why fmod?